# Light from vertex shader to fragment shader

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

Need to create a spotlight in the fragment shader to lit up a sphere. Currently i have a point light in the vertex shader and have completely no idea how to bite it.

```
 #version 140
in  vec4 vPosition;

in  vec4 vNormal;

out vec4 color;

// implicit definition: out vec4 gl_Position;

uniform mat4 model;

uniform mat4 view;

uniform mat4 projection;

uniform vec4 lPosition;

uniform vec4 lAmbient;

uniform vec4 lDiffuse;

uniform vec4 lSpecular;

uniform float Shininess;

uniform vec4 matColor;

void main() 
{
    vec4 ambient, diffuse, specular;
    vec3 N,L,E,H;

    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vPosition;
    ambient = matColor*lAmbient;

    N = normalize((view*model*vNormal).xyz);
    L = normalize((view*model*lPosition).xyz - (view*model*vPosition).xyz);
    diffuse = max(dot(L,N), 0.0)*(matColor*lDiffuse);

    E = -normalize((view * model * vPosition).xyz);
    H = normalize(L + E);
    specular = max(pow(max(dot(N, H), 0.0), Shininess)
                *lSpecular, 0.0);

    color = vec4((ambient+diffuse+specular).rgb, 1.0);
 }
```

As far as i read spotlight differs from point light, that it has the attenuation containing constant, linear and quadratic attenuation + the cutoff parameter ?

---

As far as i went:

calculating the spottlightEffect:

```
spottEffect = pow(max(dot(spotdirection, gl_Position), 0.0), spotexponent);
```

calculating the Attenuation:

```
att = (1 / (const_attenuation + linear_attenuation * (view*model*lPosition) + quadratic_attenuation * (view*model*lPosition) * (view*model*lPosition))).xyz;
```

It should be correct, as I understand the articles correctly, though no idea what to do next... Add the if statement for cut-off ?

Comment: Just pass whatever data you need through varyings like any other data. What opengl version are you using?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't put the spot light uniforms in the fragment shader?

Comment: no - ok now i now how to pass them, but no idea how to implement the spotlight. its opengl3. I have all the variables like constant attenuations, cutoff etc.

Comment: @mjanisz1, you still need help?

Comment: @elect no, thank You:)

Comment: Ok, anyway, let me just suggest you this [sample](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial21/tutorial21.html) regarding spotlights and you should really use UBO for the future, you may want to take a look to this [UBO sample](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/blob/master/jogl-samples/src/tests/Gl_320_buffer_uniform.java)